# How to fix "Call to a member function xy on array" without using foreach?

Tags: php, magento2

I have an object inside an array stored in the variable `$image`

```
array(1) { [250]=> object(Magento\Framework\DataObject)#11025 (1) { ["_data":protected]=> array(26) { ["value_id"]=> string(3) "250" ["file"]=> string(58) "/i/n/insetktenschutz-doppeltuer-im-zargenrahmen_37_1_3.jpg"  ... } } }
```

If I try to return a value, e.g. file like this:

```
echo $image->getFile();
```

Then of course I get **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFile() on array**

So I tried to call it like this:

```
$image = $image[0];
echo $image->getFile();
```

But I get **Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: 0**

So I tried to cast it to an object:

```
$image = (object) $image;
echo $image->getFile();
```

Now I get **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::getFile()**

Then I used a `foreach`:

```
foreach($image as $i) {
    echo $image->getFile();  // alternative: $image->getData('file')
}
```

and it works! Why does it work with foreach and how can I make it work without?

Comment: The array key is `250`, not `0`. Does this key have any relevance? Will it always be the same? Will there be more than one item in the array?

Comment: If you just need to access the first / only item in an array, without knowing the key, then you can use `current()`.

Comment: Yes, you did use `0`, but the array didn't have a key `0`, it has a key `250`. As shown in your first code sample. If the array may contain more than one item, then you're probably supposed to loop through them all; except if you have a very specific reason to only process the first element.

Comment: @deceze, Thank you, now I understand. The array can contain multiple image data, but sometimes only one. I solved it thanks to Khushbu's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with **reset** array function of PHP to get first element of array

```
$imageData = reset($image);
echo $imageData->getData("file");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is anything like a functional forEach in php, anyway you could make an ArrayObject subclass in order to encapsulate the iteration logic

```php
class MyArray extends ArrayObject {
    public function getData($data){
        foreach($this as $element) {
            $element->getData($data);
        }
    }
}

// and use it
$my = new MyArray(array( /* put your objects here */ ));
$my->getData("file");
```

EDIT

a more generic version

```
class MyArray extends ArrayObject {
    public function __call($name, $data){
        foreach($this as $element) {
            $element->$name(...$data);
        }
    }
}
$my = new MyArray(array( /* put your objects here */ ));
$my->getData("file");
```